# how to fix setGlobalHandler ? (react-native)

Tags: typescript, xcode, react-native, bundle

I'm setting up a React Native project repository, but when I run the Xcode simulator,

I encountered an issue with the 'main.jsbundle' file being undefined.

I was able to resolve the 'no bundle' problem by referring to the link below, but then another issue occurred that I couldn't solve even after searching. Can you help me?

https://onexlab-io.medium.com/no-bundle-url-present-fixed-ca2688a80f66

My problem screen is as shown in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfNSj.png)

```
Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'setGlobalHandler' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setGlobalHandler' of undefined
    at anonymous ()
    at h (/Users/~/main.jsbundle:2:1789)
    at d (/Users/~/main.jsbundle:2:1250)
    at i (/Users/~/main.jsbundle:2:501)
    at anonymous (/Users/~/main.jsbundle:43:85)
    at h (/Users/~/main.jsbundle:2:1789)
    at d (/Users/~/main.jsbundle:2:1250)
    at i (/Users/~/main.jsbundle:2:501)
    at global (/~/main.jsbundle:800:4)

anonymous
    main.jsbundle:65:142
h
    main.jsbundle:2:1789
d
    main.jsbundle:2:1250
i
    main.jsbundle:2:501
anonymous
    main.jsbundle:43:85
h
    main.jsbundle:2:1789
d
    main.jsbundle:2:1250
i
    main.jsbundle:2:501
global
    main.jsbundle:800:4
```